# Mixing a type parameter into the instance type of a class

Tags: typescript, class

Is there a way to have a class with dynamic index structure based on its attribute?

I've been trying to wrap my head around this, I was able to make this index signature using `type` but I can only implement an interface. Is there a different syntax for this in classes/interfaces or is it just not possible?

```
interface BaseAttributes {
    id: string;
}

class One<A extends BaseAttributes> {
    //1023: An index signature parameter type must be 'string' or 'number'.
    [key: keyof A]: A[key];

    constructor(attr: A) {
        for(const key in attr) {
            this[key] = attr[key]; // I want to type this
        }
    }
}

interface TwoAttributes extends BaseAttributes{
    label: string;
}

class Two extends One<TwoAttributes> {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I messed with this for a few minutes and couldn't find any way to define a class whose instance type includes a type variable like you want; see [this issue comment](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4890#issuecomment-141879451) for the reason.  Note, even though the issue is marked fixed and its title seems to describe what you want, AFAICT the title actually refers to the base constructor function being a type parameter (which is what mixin classes allow), not the instance type including a type parameter.

The closest I came was to write the `One` class untyped and then cast it to a generic constructor function so you can extend it with any concrete type specified for `A`:

```
interface BaseAttributes {
    id: string;
}

class OneUntyped {
  constructor(attr: {}) { 
    Object.assign(this, attr);
  }
}
const One = OneUntyped as {new<A extends BaseAttributes>(attr: A): OneUntyped & A};

interface TwoAttributes extends BaseAttributes{
    label: string;
}

class Two extends One<TwoAttributes> {
}

let two: Two;
console.log(two.label);

// Error: Base constructor return type 'OneUntyped & A' is not a class or interface type.
class Three<A extends BaseAttributes> extends One<A> { }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've decided to just write all the attributes separately and use the Object.assign approach as it feels cleaner and I can also clearly see all the attributes when I open one of the class which extend the base (`One`).